# How to use multiple depth handler in AWS Lambda with container images (python3.9)?

Tags: python, lambda, dockerfile, amazon-ecr

The below one is my application directory. There is `lambda_handler` function on the `main.py` file.

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── app
    └── src
        └── main.py
```

The below one is my `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY /app /app

RUN yum -y install gcc libmariadb-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev python-devel mysql-devel
RUN /var/lang/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -U poetry
RUN poetry export --only main --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/src
ENTRYPOINT ["/lambda-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["main.lambda_handler"]
```

I push my image to ECR with GitHub Actions and use it on Lambda. However, when I trigger the function, it raises module not found error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'main'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "...",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Additionally, I use other packages from `src` modules like the one below.

```
from typing import Any

from src.custom import Function

def lambda_handler(event: dict[str, Any], context: Any):
    Function...
```

How should I write the `Dockerfile` to work Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are having problems with the paths in the Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
    
COPY app/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN yum -y install gcc libmariadb-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev python-devel mysql-devel
RUN /var/lang/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -U poetry
RUN poetry export --only main --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -t ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/src
CMD ["main.lambda_handler"]
```

I'm not sure about the RUN steps but I think that would solve the not found module "main" issue